# Android Canvas SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm wondering about one specific behavior about drawing to the screen using `SurfaceView` and Canvas.

When i'm locking the canvas for manipulating the Pixels of the screen in my `SurfaceView`, there is one thing you always need to do: overdraw the previous pixels of the canvas with e.g. a color like black or so.

Now sometimes it happened to me that i forgot this and my previous drawings where visible in the current frames.

Furthermore it is like each layer would be drawn again and again as if there were not only one(or two because on Android drawings are tripple buffered) buffer but there are generated even more buffers and the pixel data seems to be loaded out from them layer by layer.

So the drawings are not just overdrawn but drawn layer by layer as already mentioned. Beside the Fact that it looks like animated and not going with the "vsync" (refreshrate) of the display plus leaving me wondering about performance issues, it is also a fact that annoys me because i can't figure out why the pixels are set desperately.

It should be like this:

i draw a circle at x,y on first frame
then on 2nd i draw the circle at x+1,y+1

now there will be two circles on canvas because i haven't overwritten the first frames pixels

now going on like this and drawing the circle each frame at another position....

now lets assume we are on frame 1234th

it just seems now as if every circle is drawn separately like it starts to draw than at a certain time the surfaceflinger comes and want a buffer for displaying he just catches one of the backbuffers that are not ready drawing the 1234 circles and displays it

(i hope you understand now what i mean when i say the drawings look animated)

he is just showing the screen in different drawing states

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full description of the various mechanisms can be found in the [Android Graphics Architecture document](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

The Surface is usually double-buffered, but can be triple-buffered.  If it's double-buffered, and you draw 1000 circles, one buffer will have all of the even-numbered circles, and one buffer will have all of the odd-numbered circles.  If it's triple-buffered, then one buffer will have circles 0, 3, 6, ..., another will have circles 1, 4, 7, ..., and so on.  Every time you draw, it cycles to the next buffer, so you will see the circles "vibrate" or "animate" every time you draw to the screen.

This behavior is not guaranteed -- the number of buffers is not fixed, and there's no assurance that a given buffer will continue to be used after it is swapped out -- so you wouldn't want to rely on this.

If you don't want to clear the screen each time, you can specify a "dirty" rect, and only draw in that area.  The system can reject your dirty rect and replace it with a larger one, but that should only happen on the first ever draw cycle (since there's no previous pixel data to preserve).

Comment: Actually I am posting this because i have studied this link that you posted allready and didnt find an answer

Comment: Bear in mind that `Canvas` doesn't hold pixels. It just holds the drawing context. When you lock the buffer, you're given a new Canvas to work with. You don't draw circles on the *Canvas*, you draw them onto the Surface buffer.

Comment: Actually I am posting this because i have studied this link that you posted allready and didnt find an answer. "The BufferQueue for a display Surface is typically configured for triple-buffering; but buffers are allocated on demand."...one buffer is displayed the two others are used for the next frames....but your answer seems to be correct and now it is logical for me when i think about it...and you're right with double buffering when->"So if the producer generates buffers slowly enough there might only be two allocated buffers in the queue." thank you !!!!

Comment: youre right I dont complain since i am locking the canvas of the surface i get to manipulate the pixel data of the surface....it is just the wrong statements i am using

Comment: again thank you for your answer fadden it really helped me to understand this "special behaviour" .... i would like to upvote your answer but i have not enough rep points so ->+1